# Concat data from different rows into one in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation, string-aggregation

i want to concat my data from a particular column which is present in different rows.

The Data is something like this:

```
id | Name |
1 | Jack, John |
2 | John |
3 | John, Julie |
4 | Jack | 
5 | Jack, Julie |
```

I want the output as `Jack, John, Julie`. Every name should be unique.

I tried using `string_agg(distinct Name)`, but the result is coming out as (`Jack, John, John, John, Julie, Jack, Jack, Julie`).
How can i solve this issue and get desired result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: Thanks, Noted for future but its how the concerned person wants the data to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select string_agg(distinct trim(nm), ', ') as names
from your_table, unnest(split(name)) nm
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? if it works, please mark as answer

```
WITH DistinctValues AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
       V.DenormalisedData,
       SS.[Value]
FROM (VALUES((Select SUBSTRING(( SELECT ',' + trim(Name) AS 'data()' FROM TableName FOR XML PATH('') ), 2 , 9999))))V(DenormalisedData)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.DenormalisedData,',') SS)


SELECT STRING_AGG(DV.[Value],',') AS RedenormalisedData
FROM DistinctValues DV
GROUP BY DenormalisedData;
```